# reformat existing array to group items together

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have the following array:

```
  Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => bss2
        [label] => front
        [text] => just a testing item
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => bss3
        [label] => front top
        [text] => front top testing item
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => J334
        [label] => back top
        [text] => masking test back top
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => J3366
        [label] => back
        [text] => back non mask test 
    )
```

)

What i would like to accomplish is to check to see if label = front then group the ones with front together and same with back all in one big array to have it looks like so:

```
[approval] => Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [name] => front
        [prev] => Array(
            [0]=>Array(
                [name] => bss2
            )
            [1]=>Array(
                [name] => bss2
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array(
         [name] => back
         [prev] => Array( 
            [0]=>Array(
                [name] => J334
            )
            [1]=>Array(
                [name] => J3366
            )
        )
    )
)
```

so far I dont have much and am stuck but this is my code

```
    foreach($info as $data) {

        if(strtolower(strpos($data['label'], "front") !==false)) {

        } else {

        }

    }
```

Iv also tried using array_chunk which works great but what would happen if there are 3 elements that need to be grouped or 4

```
   array_chunk($info, 2);
```

or what would happen if the order is different where one is front and second is back it will then combine the front and back together.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the strpos be executed after the strtolower?  strpos gives a number indication the position of the substring.  You'll also need to "explode" to split the strings that have "front" in them.  Then use something like "in_array" to see if "front" is in the exploded array.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, assuming the only choices are `front` and `back`.

```
$result = array(array('name' => 'front', 'prev' => array()),
                array('name' => 'back', 'prev' => array()));

foreach ($info as $data) {
    $i = (strpos(strtolower($data['label']), "front") !== false) 
    $result[$i]['prev'][] = array('name' => $data['name'];    
}

$newinfo = array('approval' => $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me exactly what you're after... If it's just `front` and `back` or if you want `top` and any other group as well?

## Methods

Anyway, here are a few options that *should* cover most cases.

### Front and Back only

This is the simplest and will just check for `front` and `back`. If it finds them then it will ad to `front` and `back` in `$newArray` as is required.

```
$newArray = array(array('front'), array('back')); //The new reformatted array

for($i = 0; $i < count($initialArray); $i++){
    if(strpos($initialArray[$i]['label'], 'front') !== FALSE){//Check if group is front
        $newArray[0]['prev'][] = array('name'=>$initialArray[$i]['name']); //Add to front
    }
    if(strpos($initialArray[$i]['label'], 'back') !== FALSE){//Check if group is back
        $newArray[1]['prev'][] = array('name'=>$initialArray[$i]['name']); //Add to back
    }
}
```

### Pre-defined groups

This one's a bit more complex and will search for all groups found in `$groups`. The code below shows only `front` and `back` but you could also add in, for example, `top` or any others.

```
$groups = array('front', 'back');   //Groups to search for e.g. front, back, and top
$newArray = array(); //The new reformatted array

for($i = 0; $i < count($initialArray); $i++){
    foreach($groups as $group){
        if(strpos($initialArray[$i]['label'], $group) !== FALSE){//Check if group is in label
            $groupKey = array_search($group, $groups); //Search for the key in $groups
            $newArray[$groupKey]['prev'][] = array('name'=>$initialArray[$i]['name']); //Add to relevant group
        }
    }
}
```

### Automated

This is the most advanced code which will automatically search and add new groups as they are found in the array. It's also fully automated so all you have to do is point it at the correct array.

```
$groups = array();   //Index of groups like: top, front, and back
$newArray = array(); //The new reformatted array

for($i = 0; $i < count($initialArray); $i++){
    $possibleGroups = explode(' ', strtolower($initialArray[$i]['label'])); //Get list of applicable groups

    foreach($possibleGroups as $newGroup){
        if(!in_array($newGroup, $groups)){ //If group doesn't already exist in $groups add it
            $groups[] = $newGroup;
            $newArray[] = array('name'=>$newGroup, 'prev'=>array());
        }

        $groupKey = array_search($newGroup, $groups); //Search for the key in $groups
        $newArray[$groupKey]['prev'][] = array('name'=>$initialArray[$i]['name']); //Add to relevant group
    }
}
```

## Test array

The above codes have been tested with the following array...

```
$initialArray = array(
    array(
            'name' =>'bss2',
            'label'=>'front',
            'text' =>'sometihng...'
        ),
    array(
            'name' =>'bss3',
            'label'=>'front top',
            'text' =>'sometihng...'
        ),
    array(
            'name' =>'j334',
            'label'=>'back top',
            'text' =>'sometihng...'
        ),
    array(
            'name' =>'j3366',
            'label'=>'back',
            'text' =>'sometihng...'
        )
);
```

## Example Output

Output of the third method (automated) using the test array above.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'front',
    'prev' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'bss2',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'bss3',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'top',
    'prev' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'bss3',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'j334',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'back',
    'prev' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'j334',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'name' => 'j3366',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```